# How do I fix this html code to make the required table?

Tags: html

I have to make a table using the table element in HTML. The table should look like this: [required Table image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2d8IH.png)

But at the moment my table looks like this: [My Table image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1lMyL.png)
I've tried to fix it numerous times. but I just can not figure it out. 
heres my HTML code aswell.
Please help

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset=utf-8 />
    <title>Page header</title>
</head>
    <body>
        <table border="1" width="100%"> 
            <tr>    
                <td colspan=4>Page Header </td>
            </tr>       

            <tr>
                <td rowspan=2>Menu: </td>
                <td> Advertisement Space </td>
                <td> Blog Links </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td> Main Content Area</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td colspan=4>Footer </td>
            </tr>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You don't have tabular data there, so you shouldn't be using a table. We've had CSS for almost two decades now, it is the correct tool for performing layout on the WWW.

Comment: Only use tables if it's tabular data!
Create the layout with divs instead. Maybe something like this http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_layout.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The HTML below creats a table like this:
[image: the resulting table]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset=utf-8 />
    <title>Page header</title>
</head>
    <body>
        <table border="1" width="100%"> 
            <tr>    
                <td colspan=4>Page Header </td>
            </tr>       

            <tr>
                <td rowspan=2>Menu: </td>
                <td colspan=2> Advertisement Space </td>

            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td> Main Content Area</td>
                <td> Blog Links </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td colspan=4>Footer </td>
            </tr>
    </body>
</html>
```

What you need to change:

- Set `colspan` for the "Advertisment Space"
- Move "Blog Links" to the same row as "Main Content Area"

Although I must say that tables are absolutely not state of the art when it comes to designing a website layout. `<table>` is used do display data (like a list or, well, a table).
`<div>` and `<span>` should be used to apply a layout to a website

Answer (score 0):

Just correct with:

```
<td rowspan="2"> Blog Links </td>
```

Side comment: you seem to be building the layout of the page using html tables. Bad idea, [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/83073/).

Also, html attributes, to be correct, require quotes, i.e. `<elem attrib="value">`

Answer (score 0):

Close off your table:

```
<table border="1" width>Table data...</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Give menu rowspan 4 and change accordingly.